# Style divs to be symmetric in two lines with flexbox

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

[image]

I want to make bottom circles to be symetric which means I want 5th circle to be between 1st and 2nd (but still below) and 7th circle to be between 3rd and 4th.

I'm displaying this circles in `v-for` loop. I have them all in one container so I'm using flex-wrap on parent and width: 25% on child.

[codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-oszx0)

Comment: Is circle count is static or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sandbox that you have provided use `justify-content: center;` for your `.container`